# Python Argparse append with nargs= >1

Tags: python, argparse

So I am trying to create a parser which can take an arbitrary list of choices (things to plot), with optional parameters specified for each choice.  And have eschewed the idea of sub-subparsers for just using multiple arguments of the form:

```
--plot foo --xlim 0 10 --ylim -5 5 --plot bar --xlim -5 5 --ylim 0 10 --clim 1e24 1e27
```

But I can't seem to get an append action to work with nargs=2:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append', nargs=2, type=int)
_AppendAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=2, const=None, default=None,  type=<type 'int'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args("--foo 1 2 --foo 3 4")
usage: [-h] [--foo FOO FOO]
: error: unrecognized arguments: - - f o o   1   2   - - f o o   3 4
```

I was hoping that I would get a list of lists or a list of tuples. Is is my desired behaviour unsupported by argparse or am I just doing something wrong in my implementation?

Comment: Didn't you notice how `parse_args` is called [in the examples](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax)? They always use `parse_args('--foo 1 2'.split())`. Note the final `.split()` that turns a string into a list of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass a list of strings, not a string:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append', nargs=2, type=int)
_AppendAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=2, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'int'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(["--foo", "1", "2", "--foo", "3", "4"])  # <----
Namespace(foo=[[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```